# @Value - lombok and mapstruct to another @value object

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

When I map a JSON Lombok @Value DTO to JPA @Value entity class and vice versa, compilation an exception thrown.

> "does not have an accessible parameterless constructor"

Java 11, hibernate, spring boot 5, Lombok, and map struct 1.3.1 are being used.

Comment: I tried https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/07/mapstruct-and-lombok/   not work "vice versa"

Comment: Can anyone explain the reason for a downvote? I know what does it mean. I need clarity why do they do it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MapStruct version used needs a parameterless/no-argument constructor (c.f https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/73).

You would need to use MapStruct version 1.4.0.Beta1; or create a no-argument constructor and don't use @Value.

Comment: Do you mean it is a known limitation? Isn't it? Any work around. Looks like they are going add 1.4. Only beta there. Let me ry now.

Comment: @bobs_007 I edited the answer for it to be clear. Yes, it is a limitation of mapstruct before 1.4.0.Beta1. You can try with this version. Otherwise you would need to change your DTO classes or don't use mapstruct with them.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the order of the annotation processor paths in Maven/Gradle file resolves the issue. Just make sure that Lombok should come after Mapstruct.

**Using Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
  ...
  annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor")
  annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok") <<=== Lombok after mapstruct
  ...
}
```

**Using Maven:**

```
<plugin>

  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>

  <configuration>
      <source>${java-version}</source>
      <target>${java-version}</target>

      <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>

      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct-version}</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>   <<=== Lombok after Mapstruct
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
        </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>

  </configuration>

<plugin>
```

I'd add the following Lombok annotations before your class:

```
@Value( staticConstructor = "of" )
@With
@Builder
```

Further, if you want Lombok to add a no-args constructor for all of your *@Value* annotated classes, you'd wanna add the following into your *lombok.config* file:

```
lombok.noargsconstructor.extraprivate=true
```